# Pick image Intent independent from device

Tags: android, android-intent, device

I'm trying to have an Intent that allows user to pick a photo or a video from the phone, then post the image to a server.

Here is how I do it :

```
public void lookForMedia(View v) {
    KeyboardHelper.hideKeyboard(this, postContentEtx);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    myIntent.setType("image/*,video/*");
    myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, MEDIA_GALLERY);
}
```

Then :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MEDIA_GALLERY:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == PICTURE_SELECTED) {
                    mediaUri = data.getData();
                    ContentResolver cR = NewPostActivity.this.getContentResolver();
                    if (mediaUri == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(NewPostActivity.this, "Error while retrieving the media", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    String type = cR.getType(mediaUri);
                    if (type.startsWith("image")) {
                        mediaThumbnailImv.setImageURI(mediaUri);
                        videoUri = null;
                        thumbnailUri = null;
                        mediaRll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mediaThumbnailImv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mediaThumbnailNetworkImv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else if (type.startsWith("video")) {
                        videoUri = mediaUri;
                        mediaUri = null;
                        Bitmap videoThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(FileUtil.getRealPathFromURI(NewPostActivity.this, videoUri), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
                        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                        FileOutputStream out = null;
                        try {
                            String filename = "thumb_" + timeStamp + "kfkb.png";
                            out = new FileOutputStream(NewPostActivity.this.getFilesDir() + filename);
                            videoThumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                            thumbnailUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(NewPostActivity.this.getFilesDir() + filename));
                            mediaThumbnailImv.setImageURI(thumbnailUri);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                out.close();
                            } catch (Throwable ignore) {
                            }
                        }

                        mediaRll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mediaThumbnailImv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mediaThumbnailNetworkImv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(NewPostActivity.this, "Invalid media", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }

                }

            }
            break;
    }
}
```

It works fine on the devices I tried (Nexus 5, LG G3, Samsung Galaxy S3, Wiko Cink Five), but some users told me that they couldn't see their photos or videos when clicking on the button (it seems that it occurs on older version of Android, but I cannot have more precise information right now). Is there a different way to do this, and to be sure that it works on most devices ? Is there something that I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all i think you doesn't understand correct that is the **cross-platform**.

[Cross-Platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-platform) - is the independent from OS code that will be executed equally on each OS. For each OS - will be compiled executable file. For Android - **apk**. For Windows - **exe**. etc...

To your problem. If the users complained about incorrect logic working i recommend to you several things :

- Log your stack trace with **device_info** into dump file to sdcard. And ask the user before application end - send this log to your email. Or something like this.
- Try to find alternative way for picking image. For the worst case - write your own activity and scan system for images.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the poor choice of words